# python getattr returns to handler when exactly is handler set to None?

Tags: python, handler, getattr

I'm porting a python script to .NET to make it easier to mantain and this is the first time i'm actually doing anything in python so I am heavily checking stackoverflow for every line I don't understand and I can't seem to figure this out at all.

I got a handler object which gets set by `getattr()` when name is None?

As far as I can tell from reading the code the name will never be None as it's set above properly so what does the `getattr()` actually do here?

if the instruction object was None? (I guess that's like null/Nothing?) wouldn't it raise a exception before hitting the `getattr()` line and then again I don't believe instruction can ever be None, if mnemonic is None the string would still look like `on_` so `name` will still technically never be `None`. So handler will never be `None` then why is it possible here?

```
    name = 'on_%s' % instruction.mnemonic
    handler = getattr(self, name, None)

    if handler is None:
        self.on_fail('Not implemented', instruction)
        return False
```

about 30 lines down in python the handler is used one last time here.

```
    if handler(instruction) is False:
        self.on_fail('Handler skipped', instruction)
```

Seems now the handler can accept a instruction Class i can't find any handler class that has `__init__` with instruction in it either.

Figured out a little it seems it's used with some global function mappers

```
on_cmovae = on_cmovcc
on_cmova = on_cmovcc
on_cmovbe = on_cmovcc
on_cmovb = on_cmovcc
on_cmovg = on_cmovcc
on_cmovge = on_cmovcc
on_cmovl = on_cmovcc
on_cmovle = on_cmovcc
on_cmove = on_cmovcc
on_cmovne = on_cmovcc
on_cmovs = on_cmovcc
```

which map back to a function

```
def on_cmovcc(self, i):
    self.writer.putlnc('if (%s)', i.get_condition_value())
    self.writer.indent()
    self.set_op(i.op1, i.op2.get())
    self.writer.dedent()
```

**Okay it seems getattr() is used to map to function calls by string name**

Comment: Did you read the documentation? [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) gets an attribute from an object and the third argument `None` is a default value in case there is no requested attribute. `getattr` isn not a setter.

Comment: These documentations to me are very hard to understand I can't bridge the connection from english to actual comprehension so I base all my knowledge on trail and error and I usually figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems that you use `getattr()` to map function calls by string name to a handler function which is a wrapper for the function you are trying to map over.